# Where should I declare my function so as to call it both from regular jQuery.ready() and jQuery(window).load()?

Tags: jquery

I'm calling the same function from these two different places:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    myfunction();
});
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    myfunction();
});
```

I can't seem to find where is the right place to declare the function though. For now I declare it in both places which is probably wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: The above example shows two function *calls* to `myfunction`, but not the *declaration* of `myfunction`.

Comment: You can declare it before any handlers. Also, because it's a named function without any params, no need for the anonymous function wrapper: `function myFunction() { ... } $(document).ready(myFunction); $(document).load(myFunction);`

Comment: I tried to declare it before both handlers, it triggers errors because my function uses jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide when to call your function.

Does your function need to run only when the dom is ready or when all the assets in the pages are loaded.

The first case executes the code when the dom tree is ready. 
pitfalls: let say your function is doing some layout calculation based on some assets which are not yet loaded. if you have any such case then second case is the one you need to go or you can register a particular on load event on the asset and resolve the layout calculation.

The second case only executes after all your assets are loaded html, css, js , img, third party resources etc., pitfall: lets say you have some group of assets in a cdn which takes lot of time to give response, then your function will execute only after the requests are processed.